# Video div in the centre

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with video in the centre. I couldn't make it to the centre of the div.

This is my html code.

```
<div id="aside">
     <div id="videoClip">
        <p> Check out my new video clip! </p>
        <p>
          <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
            controls preload="auto" width="400" height="300" 
                poster="my_video_poster.png" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="my_video.webm" type='video/webm'>
       </video>
        </p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and my css is this

```
#aside {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:center;
}

#aside p {
    margin:20px 0;
}

#aside img {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:400px;
}

#videoClip {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And try to check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/)

I already put videoClip `margin:0 auto;` and still it doesn't work. And also if I put `text-align:center` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the aside which is only 40% wide

and

```
#videoClip {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the surrounding `div#aside` `float: left` and `width: 40%`. This restricts the `video`, of course. When you make the `aside` full width, the `video` will be centered properly

```
#aside {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/3/)

Or just leaving out the `width` and `float` will work as well

```
#aside {
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/4/)

Comment: Hello, if i put the width 100% and its getting worse because I have 2 columns. left column is for article and right column is aside. So, i have to put float left for both div. And the width of left column is 60% while aside is 40%. So what should I do with that? Thanks.

Comment: So, you have a 60% column and a 40% column. And you want the video centered on top of these two columns?

Comment: no, i need a video centered of 40% column. Any idea?

Comment: The video shall be centered inside the 40% column? This already happens, see http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/6/show/

Comment: yeah i was wondering that was really perfect but it's not working on my side. I don't know why. uhm, can you help me to check again is there anything that I miss? [NEW JSFIDLLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Fmw/)

Comment: This is the same as mine, just remove the trailing `show` http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/6/. In the jsfiddle, the width for the 40% column is not enough. Therefor, the video overflows to the right. As soon as you enlarge the window, the right column has enough width to accommodate the video.

Comment: I understand that, but looking at jsfiddle, the width is not wide enough. Let's say the width of the website is 1200px. Definitely it's enough for include the video on Aside. What can I do?

Comment: When the website is 1200px, you must do nothing. Look at the http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/6/ and drag the middle handle to the left. You will see the 40% column grow, until it is wide enough and the video neatly centred.

Comment: Or you can look at the same as a full window http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5Df/6/show/ and adjust the window size, to see at what size the 40% column is wide enough. Or the other way round, at what size the video starts to overflow to the right.

Comment: 40% width is 480px of 1200px. And the width of the video is only 400px. It should be wide enough. Wondering why it didn't work!